How to create a Visual Studio DLL project that provides a C++20 module?
I would like to create two C++ projects under a Visual Studio solution. One will be a DLL project with some reusable code. The other, a simple command line project that uses the DLL. I also want to use C++ modules. I've done this successfully with static library projects, but not with a shared library.
I created the DLL project, set its language level to /std:c++latest, and wrote some simple module code. It compiles. I also turned off the precompiled headers in the project properties.
export module test_kit;
...

The name of my module happens to be test_kit. (It's for unit tests.)
Now in my second project, the command line app, I had a "Reference" to the first project, and write some code:
import test_kit;
int main() { ... }

I get:
error C2230: could not find module 'test_kit'

With static libraries, it's enough to simply add the reference from the one project to the static library project. What do I need to do here to get it all to link with the DLL project?

Make sure dll project is built up-to-date.
console project:
Project properties -> C++ -> Command line opition -> Add   /reference  "path to DLL project\x64\Debug\test_kit.ixx.ifc"
//The options below may not be required. I need to link the obj if using the module alone (not via dll).
Linker -> Input ->  "path to DLL project\x64\Debug\test_kit.ixx.obj"
Also, do not forget to link the lib.
Update:
Module ixx file:
#include<iostream>
export module TestModule;
export _declspec(dllexport) void MyTestModule();
void MyTestModule()
{
std::cout<<"Hello Module";
}


Thanks. That works, but it appears that I need to add those /reference \full\path\to\abc.ifc args for every module interface partition as well, so I'll probably go back to static libs. But I'd like to finish getting it to work... and I still can't quite, because it says it can't find the TestKit.lib file. It produces the .dll when it builds, but not that file. I don't know why.

If the lib is not generated, you did not export the function using __declspec(dllexport).And extern "C" is needed. Such as extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void test(); in header file and provide definition in cpp file.
void test() {  //some code; }

I didn't understand the comment, so went back to static libraries for now. Here's what I didn't understand: 1. You said "in header file", but my library doesn't have a header file, because it's using modules. 2. You said "the" function, and I didn't know which function you were referring to, because my library is a C++ library and it exports mostly classes in a namespace. It also does export a few free functions. But I'm not sure I can make them extern "C"

Do you only have module and .cpp files in your DLL? When using dumpbin to check the DLL file, are there any exported function symbols in it? If there is no symbol exported, you just need to link the module obj file instead of lib.

dumpbin /exports TestKit.dll doesn't list anything. I don't know if that's the right command; I'm relatively new to Windows dev. If I link against the .obj file(s), isn't that just like static linking? Are DLLs mainly used to export C stuff, not C++ symbols?

It is the right command. It means you did not export any C/C++ symbols in DLL. Use _declspec(dllexport) in your module file to export the symbol. See the sample I updated in answer. Then the lib file will be generated, and you can link the lib.

@Rob N ,Hi, Does the solution work for you? Use _declspec(dllexport) in your module file to export the symbol
